# The question about the existence of a symbol expresses the state of doubt in logical symbols

Tags: logic, proof-writing

I'm wondering whether or not there is a symbol that expresses uncertainty about a $p(x)$ proposition in deductive logic.

I realize that deductive logic considers all cases to be true or false, but I mean that in the context of proof first, we are not certain of the validity of the statement.

This question arose by thinking about proof in the style of proof by contradiction

In particular, the statements $A$ and $B$ are contradictory, so what makes us choose that $A$ is false and B is true? Why don't we choose the opposite?

In my opinion, the main reason is that statement $A$ was not certain of its truth, while statement $B$ we already knew was true.

Comment: You might be interested in modal logic https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_logic#Epistemic_logic. And to your last paragraph, yes it is whichever one seems true based on intuition or whichever statement has been proved prior.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for